# Business Objects 4.x: need to combine two queries similar to a UNION

Tags: reporting, business-objects

I can't seem to figure out how to combine the result of 2 Business Objects queries.

Both queries return a set of codes and a number of hours. Query 1 can have codes that do not appear in Query 2, and Query 2 can have codes that do not appear in Query 1.

The resulting report should contain all codes from both Query 1 and Query2, a column with the sum of hours from Q1 for that code, and a column with the sum of hours from Query 2 for that code. If one of the queries doesn't have a code in it, it would return a blank or 0 total.

Example:

Q1 results:
|Code|Value|
|:---|:----|
|A|15|
|A|17|
|B|12|
|D|22|
|D|35|
|E|16|
|E|9|
|E|11|

Q2 results:
|Code|Value|
|:---|:----|
|A|5|
|A|19|
|B|33|
|C|17|
|C|24|
|E|78|
|E|12|

Report:
|Code|Value1|Value2|
|----|------|------|
|A|32|24|
|B|12|33|
|C| |41|
|D|57| |
|E|36|90|
|Total|137|188|

When I create the Business Object report table as normal, only the values of Query 1 are used, and I miss the row for value C. If I flip the queries around, I miss the row for value D.

How do I set up my report to show all the code values?

Edit: Sorry for the formatting of the tables, in the preview it looks perfect. :(

Comment: Related to your edits. When I try to edit your question to format your tables they look perfect in the preview, but not like they are showing now. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is more like a [full outer join](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-full-outer-join/) than a union. In any case, here is what you need to do...

1. Ensure that your **Value** objects are measures with their aggregation function set to **Sum**. If they are not, you will need to create a variable for each **Value** object to force that sum aggregation. Like this...

> =Sum([Query 2].[Value])

2. Merge your **Code** objects from each of your queries
3. Build your table consisting of the merged **Code** object (not from either query) and your **Value** objects (or variables mentioned in step 1 if they do not have sum aggregation defined).

I created my example with the **Value** object from Query 2 not having its aggregation function set to **Sum** to illustrate how to do that. *However, if the aggregation function is set to **Sum** you do not need these variables; Web Intelligence will do the aggregation for you.*

[image]

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Noel